# Scale / Spread shows windows from all workspaces in 12.10

Tags: unity, ubuntu-tweak

I used Ubuntu Tweak to set up the lower left corner of my screen to activate scale/spread/show_windows/whatever_it's_called.  When I upgraded to 12.10, it now shows all open windows from all work-spaces.  It used to show only windows from the current workspace.  However, when I use super-W to do the same thing, it only shows windows from the current workspace.  What is going on here?  This feature is one of the main reasons that I use Unity (along with Dash and HUD), and without it working properly my productivity is hurt a lot.  Does anyone have a direction that I could look in to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Install CompizConfig Settings from the software center.  Under Window Management, click on Scale for options.  You're probably interested in the Behavior and Bindings tabs.

[image: Install via the software center]